# How to feed a Neural Network with a Complex-Valued Inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I am building a deep neural network for signal processing, and as you know the real-life signal is represented by a complex number. How can a complex-valued input be feed into a neural network? Is there any standard machine learning library for building a complex-valued neural network? Please help

Comment: Why not just treat a complex number as a two dimensional vector? Adding a feature dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Use CVNN. Seperate the real part and the imaginary part as the inputs of the CVNN.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).